# Simple way of transmitting properties to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following case:

```
 <ComponentA render={({propA, propB, propC}) => (
          <ComponentB
              propA={propA}
              propB={propB}
              propC={propC}
           />
 )}/>
```

In my real project, I have many more properties I want transmit to `ComponentB`. Is there a way to say "take all properties"?

I would like to have a shortcut to this so I don't have to copy paste all the attributes in this style. This seems like a very bad and unnecessary way of giving properties to a component.

Comment: `props => <Component {...props} />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass all other props to react class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534160/how-to-pass-all-other-props-to-react-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of destructuring the input you can use the spread operator

```
 <ComponentA render={(props) => (
          <ComponentB {...props} />
 )}/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `spread` operator:

```
const MyComponent = ({destructuredProp, ...rest}) =>{
    return(
        <>
            <ChildA value={destructuredProp} />
            <ChildB {...rest} />
       </> 
   )
}
```